# Android WireApp logs UnsatisfiedLink error: "wcall_set_video_send_state" when attempting video calls

Tags: java, android, chat

I've built the wire app from the following repository:
https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android

Using the following build directions:

> How to build locally Check out the wire-android repository. Switch to
>   latest relase branch release From the checkout folder, run ./gradlew
>   assembleProdRelease. This will pull in all the necessary dependencies
>   from Maven.

I've tried the release branch:

```
git clone https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android.git --branch release
```

And the master:

```
git clone https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android.git
```

Initially both versions gave the error:

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'wcall_set_video_send_state': undefined symbol: wcall_set_video_send_state
        at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:245)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:566)
```

However, this error can be solved by running the following command prior to opening the project in Android Studio:

> gradlew assembleProdRelease

This command also creates the apks in build/output/apks. However, the build isn't signed with either the release or debug key. I used the following tool to sign the apk:
https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer/releases

The APK is stable and runs fine, but still cannot initiate a video call. It gives the following errors:

Android 5:

> 08-24 22:53:29.877 296-881/? E/FastThread: did not receive expected
>   priority boost

Android 8:

> 08-24 23:10:02.190 406-4592/? E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase:
>   -getHardwareBufferInfo(), pcm_get_htimestamp fail, ret = -1, pcm_get_error =

Android 9 Emulator:

> 08-25 19:56:58.425 1583-3268/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying
>   enough data to HAL, expected position 4108693 , only wrote 4108320

**UPDATE:**

I thought about trying to build my own versions of the AVS libraries: following https://github.com/wireapp/wire-audio-video-signaling

The following command needs to be run:

```
make dist_android
```

> C:\work\wire-audio-video-signaling>make dist-android mk/target.mk:167:
>   *** Unknown host system.  Stop.

mk/target.mk looks like:

```
# Start by auto-determining host system and arch.
ifeq ($(HOST_OS),)
HOST_UNAME := $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(HOST_UNAME),Darwin)
HOST_OS := osx
else
ifeq ($(HOST_UNAME),Linux)
HOST_OS := linux
else
$(error Unknown host system)
endif
endif
endif
```

The Makefile doesn't seem to be setup to support Windows so I'm going to try building it from a Linux machine to see if that helps.

**UPDATE 2:**

It does build better on Ubuntu, but it eventually dies complaining about compiler arguments. [Sorry I don't have the error to hand]

But I've managed to find binary copies of the library built for Android/ARM here:
http://dl.bintray.com/wire-android/releases/com/wire/avs/

However, these libraries do not seem to solve the issue either.

**UPDATE 3:**

Tried the following:

1. Downloaded the latest version of the .aar file from the link above
2. Renamed it to avs.aar
3. Installed in app/libs
4. Uncommented the line: "implementation (name:'avs', ext:'aar')"

But I got the error:

> Program type already present: com.waz.avs.VideoCapturer$4
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   com.waz.avs.VideoCapturer$4, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

There is a another reference to the AVS library below, if you comment that out the error will go away.

However, none of these steps solve the problem.

Now I will try to build older versions of the release branch...

**Update 4: Release Branch: 2.41.359** 
[The most recent non-beta tagged release]

- No longer compiles in Android studio because some of the XML files in the layout DIR are not well formed. Those must be fixed and checked into Git since the build process checks all the files out from Git.
- The app initially runs normally and allows login, but always crashes after the edit devices screen. The app then crashes every time that you try to open it.

> 08-25 14:51:02.142 29066-29109/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-4
>       Process: com.wire, PID: 29066
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.waz.call.RequestHandler.request$1d4ff469()' on a null object
>   reference
>           at com.waz.call.FlowManager.request(FlowManager.java:365)

Note: Seems that edit devices screen is not the cause of the problem because I removed all my devices in the web app but then 2.41.359 crashes on the phone without displaying the edit devices screen.

This issue is mentioned in following threads:

- https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android/issues/1271
- https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android/issues/1288

The advice seems to be to use the avslib.so file from the production version since the provided one is inadequate to run the project.

So I've dowloaded the APK off their website:
https://wire.com/en/download/

It is version: 3.15.634 [That's older than the one in the app store: 3.16.638 though hopefully that doesn't matter].

For anyone that doesn't know, an APK is just a ZIP file so I renamed it to from .apk to .zip for purposes of obtaining libavs.so:

**Root Dir:**
[image: APK Root Dir]

**Libs Dir:**
[image: APK Libs Dir]

**Arm Dir:**
[image: APK armeabi-v7a Dir]

With libavs.so extracted, I renamed the unsigned version of wire-prod-release-2.41.99999 produced by the build tools to wire-prod-release-2.41.99999-avs-mod.zip and deleted the old libavs.so and replaced it with the one that I just took from the production version of the app. I renamed it back to .pkg then ran the following command to sign it:

```
java -jar \uber-apk-signer-0.8.4.jar --apks wire-prod-release-2.41.99999-avs-mod.apk -debug
```

Pretty good result, 2.41.359 no longer crashes. However, I still cannot initiate any audio or video calls. Same error found in the latest version of the release branch:

```
08-25 16:01:51.748 406-4592/? E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase: -getHardwareBufferInfo(), pcm_get_htimestamp fail, ret = -1, pcm_get_error =
```

As a sanity check, I installed the production version: 3.15.634 used to extra libavs.so and it is able to make both audio and video calls. [The version on GooglePlay: 3.16.638 also works fine for audio and video...]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of trying, I found a way to build the project in such a way that it will initiate audio and video calls:

Procedure:

- git clone https://github.com/wireapp/wire-android.git --branch release
- cd wire-android
- git checkout 2.40.357
- Load the project into Android Studio
- Edit the file res/layout/collection_file_asset.xml
- Move `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` above the copyright comment since the file must begin with the XML tag
- git add .
- git commit -m "fixed syntax error"
- gradlew assembleProdRelease
- java -jar \uber-apk-signer-0.8.4.jar --apks wire-prod-release-2.40.99999.apk -debug
- adb install wire-prod-release-2.40.99999-aligned-debugSigned.apk

Other Notes:

- Master currently does not build due to Scala errors...
- The current release branch produces a stable app but results in the following error when tapping on the video icon: "*E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase: -getHardwareBufferInfo(), pcm_get_htimestamp fail, ret = -1, pcm_get_error =*"
- The most recent stable release 2.41.359 does not work because it crashes on every app launch with: "*AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4 Process: com.wire, PID: 29066 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.waz.call.RequestHandler.request$1d4ff469()' on a null object reference at com.waz.call.FlowManager.request(FlowManager.java:365)*"
- While building 2.40.357 enables audio and video, it is unstable and crashes quite a bit while receiving and making calls. I've spoken with other developers using this code base and they've encountered similar problems...

Thoughts:

I'm not really sure what's happening with this project. There are developers pleading for help with audio / video issues on Git with little response. I think I'd feel a little uneasy about using this code for a commercial project unless there is a bit more stability and support...

Answer (score 0):

I gave up to compile a working application from source. Aside from educational reasons, my motivation to compile from source was a particular code change (lifting the limit of simultaneous accounts in the android app, as I have more than 2)

Doing that change itself is trivial, its just a constant defined in
app/src/main/scala/com/waz/zclient/pages/main/profile/preferences/pages/ProfileBottomSheetDialog.scala:

val MaxAccountsCount = 2

However, since no working application can be built from the provided sources - even with considerable effort -  I instead used the smali/backsmali tool from
https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali
to create a patch/diff of this particular code change between a modified and unmodified (nonfunctional) binary app built from source - reflecting the corresponding changes in bytecode. (Although apktool could probably be used to do the same)

This bytecode patch can then be applied to the precompiled and fully functional production app as well, also using smali/backsmali (or apktool)

Comment: "no working application can be built from the provided sources". I think I've come to the same conclusion though I suppose they can call it open source in their marketing materials. In my case, I just needed to get it going for a demo...